# Can a textField in subreport with "Stretch with overflow" span across multiple pages?

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a subreport with just one text field. This text field can have somewhere around 5000 characters retrieved from a service.

My goal is to show this subreport on the parent report. It should start from the "Float" position where I place it to multiple pages in a continuous manner.

When I have this subreport in my parent report, the **text clips** when the **"Stretch with overflow"** of the **text field in subreport** is set to **false**. 
When I set **"Stretch with overflow" to true**, the **text field appears blank** on the pages but takes up the required space on the parent report.

I have tried the following but nothing seem to work:

**1. In the sub report:**

> - Print when detail overflow = true
> - Split Type = "Stretch"
> - Ignore pagination = true

**2. Main report:**

> - Split Type = "Stretch"
> - Print when detail overflow = true on subreport object
> - Print in first whole band = true

Trying it since few days has made me feel that it is impossible to have a overflowing text field across pages.

Please let me know if its even possible to have a subreport with text field to span across multiple pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"its even possible to have a subreport with text field to span across multiple pages?"*

Yes I attach an example below

**Main report**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="stretchTest" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" whenNoDataType="BlankPage" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="6c8cebac-a7b5-4dc2-abe8-e36b0cb184ca">
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\jdd\\projects\\StackTrace\\jasper\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="778b107f-288e-4f17-915d-fed6f83a2805"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource(2)]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "stretchTest_subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**Subreport**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="stretchTest_subreport" pageWidth="100" pageHeight="555" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="100" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="f716e850-ab6f-4668-b3a1-afe4823b8abf">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="veryLongTextThatNeedToBreak" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["I have a subreport with just one text field. This text field can have somewhere around 5000 characters retrieved from a service. My goal is to show this subreport on the parent report.(it should start from the Float position where I place it to multiple pages in a continuous manner). When I have this subreport in my parent report, the text clips when the Stretch with overflow of the text field in subreport is set to false. When I set Stretch with overflow to true, the text field appears blank on the pages but takes up the required space on the parent report. I have tried the following but nothing seem to work:1. In the sub report: Set the Print when detail overflow = true Set Split Type = Stretch Ignore pagination = true 2. Main report: Set Split Type = Stretch Set Print when detail overflow = true of subreport object Print in first whole band = true Trying it since few days has made me feel that it is impossible to have a overflowing text field across pages. Please let me know if its even possible to have a subreport with text field to span across multiple pages. Thanks in advance!!"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="4f14a231-dd62-465b-b10a-fa39f9c6a297"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{veryLongTextThatNeedToBreak}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Compile the subreport, set correct path to subreport and test you self.

**Note**: I'm not setting a lot of attributes on the `reportElement`s.

**Output**

[image: output]

Comment: Just writing this if it helps anybody in future. I was setting way too many attributes for both the subreport and elements inside the subreport. The exact set of attributes to be set are as follows:


Parent Report :
1. Band split type = Stretch.
2. Subreport element, Stretch Type = No stretch

Subreport :
1. For text field, Stretch with overflow = true.
2. Stretch Type = No stretch
3. Band, Split Type= Stretch

Comment: Yeah, I was imaging this, you get into a mess and you mess up more when you try to get out, that why I posted a simple example (trying to break exactly where you had your doubts... : ) Thanks for accepted..